# Mock HttpResponse with redirect

Tags: java, apache

How to create org.apache.http.HttpResponse object that looks like response from web page that returns 301 MOVED_PERMANENTLY.

Most important - where to put redirection url?

I am testing web crawling application. I have created mock for my HttpClient in which I want to create response that will simulate one that will be returned when web page was redirected for example from http to https or to other domain.

For example for 200 OK I create response that way:

```
private  ProtocolVersion http11 = new ProtocolVersion("HTTP", 1, 1);
private  StatusLine HTTP_200_OK = new BasicStatusLine(http11, response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), Response.Status.OK.getReasonPhrase());
BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(HTTP_200_OK);
```

but I have problem where to put redirection url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect url is contained in an Http header (`Location`), so per the [HttpResponse](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) api docs, I think this is pretty straightforward:

```
HttpResponse res = new BasicHttpResponse (new BasicStatusLine(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY, "");
res.setHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "http://some.new/url");
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed key information that it should be in the header with field name HttpHeaders.LOCATION

Comment: Yeah, check out [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) for more. The MDN docs are super helpful for learning about Http status codes and headers and such.